# Flutter - How to get documents only that certain value does not contain in a List in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: arrays, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a users collection, each user has an id and a list of ids, I needed to get documents from firestore that the id is not on that list.

Let's say I have 3 documents in firestore with id 1, 2 and 3.

The list of the current user has the id 1 and 2.

```
List<String> ids = ["1", "2"];
```

How can I only get documents that the item "id" are not on the List of the current user? In the example it should retrieve only the document with id = 3.

for example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.collection("users").where("id", arrayNotContains(ids)).get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [not-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) operation, which allows you to specify up to 10 values in the array. If you have more than 10 IDs, you'll have to instead get all documents from the database and perform the exclusion in your application code.

If `id` is a field in the documents, that'd look something like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.collection("users").where("id", whereNotIn: ids).get();
```

If you're actually trying to filter on the document ID, instead of a field, that'd be:

```
FirebaseFirestore.collection("users").where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: ids).get();
```

Comment: If I filter on the documentID, the limit of 10 items is the same or whereNotIn can receive a List with any size?

Comment: The problem is that if I have this limit and if I get all documents at once I will get lots of documents that I won't need on my app and eventually pay for them.

Comment: The limit of 10 applies to all such filters. Explicitly excluding IDs is a non-efficient operation at scale, so Firestore doesn't support it.